# Pull-Over View in iOS 7 Similar to Control Center

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm making an iOS 7+ only app, and I need to have a view that can be pulled from the bottom of the screen, very similar to the system Control Center. Blur would be nice, but that doesn't look like an easy task, sadly.

I want to take advantage of OS 7's UIDynamicAnimator, and the Gravity/Collisions features. But I can't figure out how!

The view will cover about 3/4s of the screen, and be semi-transparent (0.6 alpha). It will contain some controls that I'd like to lay out in IB.

The view should be activated when the user 'pulls' from the bottom 0.25" on the screen. I want it to behave like the control center or lock screen - not a single swipe gesture, but a view that tracks the users' pan, and snaps up or down accordingly.